# "touchmove" event on Android &iPhone using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mousemove, touchmove

so basically I want to be able to get the coordinates of the touch when someone swipes across the screen of a touch-enable device powered by iOS or Android.

What I've tried to do so far is as follows.

```
$('element').bind("touchmove", function(e) {
    $(element2).html(e.pageX + "," + e.pageY);
}
```

plus I've tried the same with "vmousemove"(the jquery mobile equivalent or so it should be), "mousemove" but to no avail. I only get the coordinates of the the initial and end touch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS and Android are muti-touch devices. The interaction is handled using touch events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events

Comment: Precisely, I've tried using "touchmove" but the callback function is called only twice.... I am using phonegap 2.3.0 and this happens on Android 4.0.1

Comment: Yes, but you don't handle the event e correctly. You should work with e.touches. It provides an array of Touch objects.See also this: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

You're very close... All you needed was the original Event. jQuery wraps these up for you.

e.g.

```
$('element').bind("touchmove", function(event) {
   var e = ev.originalEvent;
   var touch = e.touches[0];
   $(element2).html(touch.pageX + "," + touch.pageY);
}
```

EDIT: I forgot about the touches array... my bad.